# Which index should I use for mix WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE toshow = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

The timestamp column stores current timestamp in database when inserting row. In some rows 'toshow' value is 0 and in some rows its 1

What `INDEX` should I use to get results faster for any 0  or 1 toshow value and latest row above

I created index `(timestamp, toshow)` for this but confusing its right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON mytable(toshow, timestamp DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use the where part first  as  the most selective part so could be easy used  by the where  clause

```
 index (toshow, timestamp DESC )
```

the timestamp column is used for provide   the info for order by but this happen after the filering for the rows  based on where clause

In this way the index 
It is used both to filter the lines and to obtain the formats for the sorting 
in your way the index can't be used  for where  ..